# Jarigner: unable to open jar file

Tags: android, cordova, certificate, keystore, jarsigner

I have searched a lot about this issue and everything I've found didn't seem to help.
I am trying to sign my cordova app in android with the following command:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore key_file_name.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

I have specified the directory of the apk, while the keystore is in it's default directory.. I have also tried placing the apk files in a same folder with the keystore file but I got the same error.

Please help!

Comment: did you solve it ,

Comment: Yes, I think the issue was the name of the folder in which the keystore and the alias are. The name was two words with space between them. Trying to exectue this command with a directory that contains space will throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, if you are using windows, try from command prompt and not from bash or any other tool. It fixed for me.

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore D:\motivation-pyramid\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore D:\motivation-pyramid\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-x86-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this is:

1. open project in android studio
2. go to “Build > Generate Signed APK”
3. go next page
4. click on “choose existing” button, then import your ****.keystore
   file
5. type "password" and "alias" of your keystore file
6. go next page and select your “Signature version” method, then click on finish button